# An orthonormal basis of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ which is pointwise in $\ell^{2}(\mathbb{N})$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Does there exist an orthonormal basis of the Hilbert space $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$, say $(e_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$, such that all elements $e_n\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})\cap C^{0}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ and such that for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$, the sequence $(e_{n}(x))_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset \mathbb{C}$ is in $\ell^{2}(\mathbb{N})$, i.e. such that the sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|e_{n}(x)|^{2}$$
is finite?

I was thinking about the case $d=1$, and using the basis of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ constructed from the Hermite polynomials, but I don't get enough decay to make the series converge.

Comment: Intuition suggests that the requirement that the norm of each $e_n$ be $1$ will prevent that series from converging everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer but I believe that if the statement in question is incorrect---as @eyeballfrog suggested in their comment---then any proof would start with the following argument:

Assume there exists an orthonormal basis $(e_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|e_{n}(x)|^{2}<\infty$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$.
Then the
function
\begin{align*}
f:\mathbb R^d&\to\mathbb C\\
x&\mapsto\sum_{n=1}^\infty|e_n(x)|^2
\end{align*}
is well-defined and, moreover, $f$ is the pointwise limit of the (obviously measurable) functions
\begin{align*}
f_\ell:\mathbb R^d&\to\mathbb C\\
x&\mapsto\sum_{n=1}^\ell|e_n(x)|^2\,.
\end{align*}
By [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli%27s_theorem) every $f_\ell$ is in $L^1(\mathbb R^n)$:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb R^d}|f_\ell(x)|\,{\mathrm d}\mu(x)&=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\sum_{n=1}^\ell|e_n(x)|^2\,{\mathrm d}\mu(x)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\ell\int_{\mathbb R^d}|e_n(x)|^2\,{\mathrm d}\mu(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\ell\|e_n\|_2^2=\sum_{n=1}^\ell 1=\ell<\infty\,,
\end{align*}
but $f$ is not ($\|f\|_1=\infty$).
Therefore (the contraposition of) [dominated convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement) implies that $(f_\ell)_\ell$ cannot be dominated by any integrable function, i.e. for all $g\in L^1(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R_+)$ and all $L\in\mathbb N$ there has to exist $x\in\mathbb R^d$ and $\ell>L$ such that $|f_\ell(x)|>g(x)$.

Intuitively, given $c>0$ I would choose something like $g_c:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb C$, $x\mapsto c$ if $x\in B_c(0)$ and $x\mapsto c^3\|x\|^{-2}$ else so $g_c$ is integrable, positive, continuous, but diverges pointwise as $c\to\infty$. So far, however,  I have not been able to turn this into a contradiction. Maybe someone else can complete this argument and solve the problem.